# Finding C from $\Delta C$

Tags: functions, information-theory

Define: $\Delta A(t) = A(t+1)-A(t)$ and let
$$
\Delta C = \sum^{T-1}_{t=0} [~~H(\pi(t+1)~|~\mu(t+1))~~ - ~~H(\pi(t)~|~\mu(t+1))~~]
$$
Where $H (\pi(t+1)|\mu(t+1)) = \sum^n_{i=1}\pi_i(t) \log \frac{\pi_i(t)}{\mu_i(t+1)}$ is the relative entropy.

I am confused about the following:

1. What is the definition of $C$
2. What is $C$ a function of?

**attempt**
I believe this implies that:
$$
C(s) = \sum_{t=1}^{T-1}H(s~|~\mu(t+1))
$$

Comment: The definition of $\Delta C$ does look strange.  I would say either the $\Delta$ on the LHS should not be there, or the sum on the RHS shouldn't.  Probably the latter.  As written $\Delta C$ is a number.

Comment: yeah im quite confused by it, its in a paper I am trying to figure out: page 7 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5376v1.pdf

Comment: Given a value for $\Delta C$, you could only get within a constant offset of $C$ as the difference operator has many of the same effects as taking a derivative, including losing the constant offset.

Comment: @dimebucker91 - I assume you are trying to represent the term at the end of equation $8$.  If so, you want to remove the $\Delta$ on the LHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having taken a look at the paper you mentioned in the comments I would rewrite the beginning of your post as follows:

Define: $\Delta A(t) = A(t+1)-A(t)$ and let
$$S = \sum^{T-1}_{t=0} \Delta C(t)$$
where $$\Delta C(t) = ~~H(\pi(t+1)~|~\mu(t+1))~~ - ~~H(\pi(t)~|~\mu(t+1))~~$$
and $H (\pi(t+1)|\mu(t+1)) = \sum^n_{i=1}\pi_i(t) \log \frac{\pi_i(t)}{\mu_i(t+1}$ is the relative entropy.

Here we see that $\Delta C(t)$ is a function of $t$ and the sum $S$ (what you originally called $\Delta C$) is a number.  Alternatively, if you would like to think of the $T$ as varying, then you could consider $S$ to be a function of $T$:
$$S(T) = \sum^{T-1}_{t=0} \Delta C(t)$$

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense now. I've been trying to find the derivative of C as a function of s. I guess it makes more sense to think about s as the first definition